# Gradle unknown Import configurations on creating or importing a Gradle project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

This may or may not be an existing question, but I am having the hardest time finding a solution for it.

I am totally new to Gradle and recently successfully installed Gradle 5.0, I've also installed related Eclipse plugin for it:

[image: All Gradle related Plugins are installed on Eclipse]

So, I have a sample project for Gradle which I tried to import, this is the folder Structure:

[image: Project in File system]

please refer the following screenshots leading to the importing issue:

[image: Selected Gradle Project]
[image: Project Root Directory]
[image: Added Configurations]
[image: Unknown Details; non-functional Finish button]

My Gradle seems like successfully installed, I tried to execute a simple task in "build.gradle" file from command-line without importing the project and it ran successfully.

[image: Installed Gradle]

I am really not sure what I am missing or doing wrong, I have changed Java version. 
I am using Java 8, Eclipse 2018-09, Gradle 5.0 on windows 10

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following lines in build.gradle

```
plugins {
   id 'eclipse'
}
```

Open a terminal and type

```
gradle eclipse
```

Then import your project as a existing project in eclipse

Comment: It worked! Thank you :) For other contributors Make sure you add plugin block at the top of the build.gradle file